# Cancel page load in Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am testing a page which contains a pesky iframe which takes a long time to load; however, I'm not testing the iframe itself. If possible, I'd like to be able to run my tests without having to wait for this iframe each time.

One of the following potential solutions should do the trick, but I'm having difficulty either finding documentation or getting any of them to work:

> a) Cancel the page load shortly after the request is placed.
>
> b) Simulate an <kbd>Escape</kbd> press *while* the page is loading using `send_keys` method.
>
> c) Use javascript - `page.execute_script("return window.stop();")` *while* the page is loading.
>
> d) Cancel loading of a specific element

How would one send a cancellation request to a loading page or element using Capybara?

Comment: Any luck on this? Did you manage to figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

We were having problems with outstanding network requests (both Ajax and assets) at the end of our integration tests, when all the assertions had been met and the test was over and getting torn down.

So we added `execute_script("window.stop();")` to our integration_test_helper.rb file, in the teardown block, and it worked very well.

So I'd suggest adding an assertion that can be met before your iframe is fully loaded, and running `window.stop()` in the teardown of the test.

Answer (score 0):

Altnerative here, you could use [puffing-billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy) gem to stub that iframe request.